# How to compare two NSIndexPaths?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsindexpath

I'm looking for a way to test if to index paths are equal, and by equal I mean equal on every level? I tried `compare:` but it seems not to work, I always get true when compared with `NSOrderedSame` even if the indexes are definitely not the same.

Comment: Please post your code using the compare: method.

Comment: `[itemCategoryIndexPath compare:indexPath]==NSOrderedSame` pretty straight forward, was I missing smth?

Comment: @Valentin Radu, in your previous comment, do you mean that `compare:` works, opposite to as you mentioned in your question ?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Almost all Objective-C objects can be compared using the `isEqual:` method. So, to test equality, you just need `[itemCategoryIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]`, and you're good to go. Now, this works because `NSObject` implements `isEqual:`, so all objects automatically have that method, but if a certain class doesn't override it, `isEqual:` will just compare object pointers.

In the case of `NSIndexPath`, since the `isEqual:` method has been overridden, you can compare the objects as you were to expect. But if I were to write a new class, `MyObject` and not override the method, `[instanceOfMyObject isEqual:anotherInstanceOfMyObject]` would effectively be the same as `instanceOfMyObject == anotherInstanceOfMyObject`.

---

You can read more in the [NSObject Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html).

Comment: @Itai Ferber, how do one may know, if a method has been overridden or not.

Comment: @Kailash You can't necessarily know if a method has been overridden. I think there may be a way, but I'm not sure; it's not within the realm of everyday programming - it would take some messing around with the runtime. Anyway, for the most part, there'd be no reason to need to know whether a class overrides this method, because it's providing you with functionality you need. Always use `isEqual:` on objects, and let the class itself handle the problem for you.

Comment: +1 I did not know isEqual: compared pointers when not implemented.  Good to know!

Answer (score 10):

In Swift you use `==` to compare if NSIndexPaths are the same.

```
import UIKit

var indexPath1 = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
var indexPath2 = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
var indexPath3 = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0)
var indexPath4 = indexPath1

println(indexPath1 == indexPath2) // prints "true"
println(indexPath1 == indexPath3) // prints "false"
println(indexPath1 == indexPath4) // prints "true"

println(indexPath1 === indexPath2) // prints "true"
println(indexPath1 === indexPath3) // prints "false"
println(indexPath1 === indexPath4) // prints "true"
```

Swift uses `==` for value comparisons. `===` is used for detecting when two variables reference the exact same instance (location in memory etc). Interestingly, the `indexPath1 === indexPath2` shows that NSIndexPath is built to share the same instance whenever the values (section row) match, so even if you were comparing instances, it would still be valid.

This answer taken almost completely from [this fantastic SO answer from drewag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172525/comparing-nsindexpath-swift) and reproduced here since this is the first Google result for 'compare indexpath' and we are not supposed to just paste a link.

Comment: This question is almost 4 years old, is tagged objective-c, and has an accepted answer.  I think it would be better to post this as an answer to a separate question.

Comment: Just trying to help future rookies like me. This is the #1 result when you Google 'compare indexPath'. I will ask a separate question and post this answer but people are going to be finding this first for a long time. :)

Comment: Actually the question was already asked, like I mentioned in my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172525/comparing-nsindexpath-swift - But even the onsite search doesn't show that question when you search for 'compare indexpath swift'. It just shows this answer. So I am going to leave my answer here to point people there.

Comment: Now that you posted the link to the other question it shows up in the side bar. Hopefully it will help someone in the future like you said- the objective-c and swift waters are definitely muddled.

Comment: This helped me bro. I'm looking for Swift and got to this post.