# Comparing NSIndexPath Swift

Tags: swift, nsindexpath

If I have a NSIndexPath constant declared for a UITableView, is it valid to compare using the `==` operator?

This is my constant declaration:

```
let DepartureDatePickerIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0)
```

And then my function:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    var height: CGFloat = 45

    if indexPath == DepartureDatePickerIndexPath{
        height = departureDatePickerShowing ? 162 : 0
    } else if indexPath == ArrivalDatePickerIndexPath {
        height = arrivalDatePickerShowing ? 162 : 0
    }

    return height
}
```

This certainly works properly, but is it safe to do? I'm assuming that since it works, the `==` operator on the NSIndexPath object is comparing the section and row properties instead of the instance.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Let's do a very simple test:

```
import UIKit

var indexPath1 = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
var indexPath2 = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
var indexPath3 = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0)
var indexPath4 = indexPath1

println(indexPath1 == indexPath2) // prints "true"
println(indexPath1 == indexPath3) // prints "false"
println(indexPath1 == indexPath4) // prints "true"

println(indexPath1 === indexPath2) // prints "true"
println(indexPath1 === indexPath3) // prints "false"
println(indexPath1 === indexPath4) // prints "true"
```

Yes, it is safe to use `==` with NSIndexPath

As a side note, `==` in Swift is always for value comparisons. `===` is used for detecting when two variables reference the exact same instance. Interestingly, the `indexPath1 === indexPath2` shows that NSIndexPath is built to share the same instance whenever the values match, so even if you were comparing instances, it would still be valid.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to be sure. If it had been Objective-C, the `==` operator would have compared the instances?

Comment: @Shan, that is correct. That is because `==` is actually defined in C. So you are comparing the two pointers in Objective-C (are the two variables pointing to the same place in memory). Swift moved away from C and all classes have to define their own `==` operator. All instances of NSObject use `isEqual:` from Objective-C for `==` comparison

Comment: I suppose this works too for collection view index paths (which have `item` instead of `row`)

Answer (score 1):

With Swift, you can use `NSIndexPath` or `IndexPath`. Both have the same strategy to compare.

---

## #1. `NSIndexPath`

According to Apple Documentation, [`NSIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsindexpath) conforms to [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) protocol. Therefore, you can use `==` or `!=` operators in order to compare two instances of `NSIndexPath`.

---

## #2. `IndexPath`

Apple documentation states about `NSIndexPath` and `IndexPath`:

> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the `IndexPath` structure, which bridges to the `NSIndexPath` class.

This means that, as an alternative to `NSIndexPath`, starting with Swift 3 and Xcode 8, you can use [`IndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexpath). Note that `IndexPath` also conforms to `Equatable` protocol. Therefore, you can use `==` or `!=` operators in order to compare two instances of it.