# indexPath comparison in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am storing selected `indexPath` inside a mutabledictionary `selectedRowsInSectionDictionary as follows.

For example in the following dictionary it shows, first section which is key. And in this section, first (1,0), second(1,1) and third(1,2) rows has been chosen and stored inside the dictionary.

[image]

I am trying to check whether or not these `indexPath` is stored inside the dictionary in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method, but it always returns false. i am wondering what I am doing wrong?

```
if([selectedRowsInSectionDictionary objectForKey:@(indexPath.section)] == indexPath)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Comment: try isEqual: method in replace of == in your comparison conditional. Also make sure that the object returned from the dictionary is actually an NSIndexPath object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two NSIndexPaths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379101/how-to-compare-two-nsindexpaths)

Comment: @ShamasS, actually my question is sligthly different, I have an array of indexPathes to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[selectedRowsInSectionDictionary objectForKey:@(indexPath.section)]` is an `NSMutableArray` reference, not an `indexPath`, so the comparison will never be true.

I would suggest that you store `NSMutableIndexSet` in your dictionary, rather than an array.  Your code would then be something like:

```
NSMutableIndexSet *selectedSet = selectedRowsInSectionDictionary[@(indexPath.section)];
if ([selectedSet containsIndex:indexPath.row] {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

To add/remove items to the dictionary using a 'toggle' you would use:

```
NSMutableIndexSet *selectedSet = selectedRowsInSectionDictionary[@(indexPath.section)];

if (selectedSet == nil) {
    selectedSet = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
    selectedRowsInSectionDictionary[@(indexPath.section)] = selectedSet;
}

if ([selectedSet containsIndex:indexPath.row]) {
    [selectedSet remove:indexPath.row];
} else {
    [selectedSet add:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: It shows the following error no visible interface for `NSMutableIndexSet` has `contains` method.

Comment: Sorry, there is a difference between the Swift and Objective-C method names.  I have updated it

Comment: do you have any idea for the related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483622/reload-section-does-not-handle-properly

Answer (score 1):

This is failing as the value of the dictionary is an array.

As far as I can tell

```
[selectedRowsInSectionDictionary objectForKey:@(indexPath.section)]
```

Will return an array containing 3 elements (The NSIndexPaths). 
You should be able to modify your code to the following:

```
if([[selectedRowsInSectionDictionary objectForKey:@(indexPath.section)] containsObject:indexPath]
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

I have confirmed this with the following testing code:

```
NSIndexPath *comparisonIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
NSDictionary *test = @{ @(1): @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0],
                                comparisonIndexPath,
                                [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0]]};
NSArray *indexPathArray = [test objectForKey:@(1)];
if ([indexPathArray containsObject:comparisonIndexPath]) {
    NSLog(@"Yeeehawww, let's do some stuff");
}
```