# Reload Section does not handle properly

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have the following implementation where I have `title`, and two buttons(titles are `half` and `full`) on the tablecell. When user selects and close the section and open it again, he only sees the default values of button title which is `full` rather than his selection.

I could able to see the following method (`setHalfButton :indexPath`
) is getting called during the reloading, but it does not have any effect.

Code and screenshots are follows.

```
- (void)selectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath setQuantity :(double) quantity  {
    NSMutableArray* array = [selectedRowsInSectionDictionary objectForKey:@(indexPath.section)];
    if(array){
        [array addObject:indexPath];
    } else {
        array = [NSMutableArray array];
        [array addObject:indexPath];
        [selectedRowsInSectionDictionary setObject:array forKey:@(indexPath.section)];
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{          
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ComboCell";
    ComboTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[ComboTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    if([selectedRowsInSectionDictionary[@(indexPath.section)] containsObject: indexPath])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        if(
       comboItemsArray[indexPath.section].allComboItems[indexPath.row].pQuantity == 0.5)
         {
            // it comes here after reloading
             [self setHalfButton:indexPath];
         }
         else
         {
             [self setFullButton:indexPath];
         }
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.halfBtnOutlet.hidden = YES;
        cell.fullBtnOutlet.hidden = YES;
    }
    cell.comboTitle.text =comboItemsArray[indexPath.section].allComboItems[indexPath.row].pName;

    [cell.halfBtnOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(halfBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.fullBtnOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(fullBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
}

-(void) setHalfButton : (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    ComboTableViewCell* cell = [comboTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.halfBtnOutlet setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:102.0f/255.0f blue:0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.fullBtnOutlet setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5f green:0.5f blue:0.5f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.halfBtnOutlet.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.f]];
    [cell.fullBtnOutlet.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.f]];
}

-(void) setFullButton : (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    ComboTableViewCell* cell = [comboTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.fullBtnOutlet setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:102.0f/255.0f blue:0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.halfBtnOutlet setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5f green:0.5f blue:0.5f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.fullBtnOutlet.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.f]];
    [cell.halfBtnOutlet.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.f]];
}
```

Comment: Hi Paulw11, please put it as an answer, then I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setHalfButton` and `setFullButton` functions are being called from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` datasource method, but they are calling the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` tableview method.  Since you have not yet returned the cell from the former method, the latter method will return `nil` to `cell`, resulting in no visible update.

The `setHalfButton` and `setFullButton` methods should be in your `ComboTableViewCell` class:

```
-(void) setHalfButton 
{
    [self.halfBtnOutlet setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:102.0f/255.0f blue:0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.fullBtnOutlet setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5f green:0.5f blue:0.5f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.halfBtnOutlet.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.f]];
    [self.fullBtnOutlet.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.f]];
}

-(void) setFullButton
{
    [self.fullBtnOutlet setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:102.0f/255.0f blue:0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.halfBtnOutlet setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5f green:0.5f blue:0.5f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.fullBtnOutlet.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.f]];
    [self.halfBtnOutlet.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.f]];
}
```

Also, you are adding the button action handlers each time you dequeue a cell, but you should only do this when you allocate a new cell.  From a design point-of-view these button tap handlers should also be in your `ComboTableViewCell` class with a delegation pattern to notify the view controller that the half/full was changed.

At the very least it should look something like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{          
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ComboCell";
    ComboTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[ComboTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        [cell.halfBtnOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(halfBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.fullBtnOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(fullBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    if([selectedRowsInSectionDictionary[@(indexPath.section)] containsObject: indexPath])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        if(
       comboItemsArray[indexPath.section].allComboItems[indexPath.row].pQuantity == 0.5)
         {
            // it comes here after reloading
             [cell setHalfButton];
         }
         else
         {
             [cell setFullButton];
         }
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.halfBtnOutlet.hidden = YES;
        cell.fullBtnOutlet.hidden = YES;
    }
    cell.comboTitle.text =comboItemsArray[indexPath.section].allComboItems[indexPath.row].pName;


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed clarification!

Comment: Any idea for the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48605676/nssingleobjectarrayi-decimalvalue-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance